# Having a problem with "having"

Tags: gerund-clauses

Consider the following sentence:

> In one study, 83 percent of 140 male and female executives in variety of businesses **report having a mentor when they were younger.**

More specifically,

> ...(they) report having a mentor when they were younger.

I am confused with the grammatical structure of the sentence. My inference is

> They report that they had a mentor when they were young.

It can be seen that the "having a mentor when they were younger" play role of object in that sentence.

I am confused with the sentence, especially with "having".

Perhaps, **having a mentor when they were younger** is a noun clause. I am not sure about it.

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit explanation :
The missing article, a , has been corrected

Comment: Just a note, you don't generally need to explain your edit in the content of the question. That's what the edit summary is for on the edit page, which you don't seem to be using. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *having a mentor when they were younger* is a **noun clause**, but **not a noun phrase**. The difference is that a noun clause is an entire clause **acting as a noun** in the main clause and a noun phrase is a phrase **built around a noun**. Here are some examples:

> - He is **the *man* in red**. (noun phrase)
> - That is **the *man* who I saw yesterday**. (noun phrase)
> - I told you **that I saw a man yesterday**. (noun clause)

Note how the noun phrase is built around the noun *man*. The third example also contains *man*, but it is not the core of your phrase.

For the sake of readability, I'd make a few adjustments to your sentence:

First of all, *having a mentor...* can be put in the past tense, even as a gerund. You should do that here, because *when they were younger* implies that the event being described has passed and is no longer true in the present. So, reformulate like so:

> ...*having had* a mentor...

However, because your direct object (the noun clause in this case) is quite long, going with a gerund might not be very tidy. Try using a subordinate clause by using the conjunction *that*. It will make your sentence more readable:

> They report ***that*** they had a mentor when they were younger.

Comment: In the first example I can see an adjective clause.Which part of it is a noun phrase ?  am I right ?

Comment: And the last highlighted sentence in your answer is exactly my inference which is given in the question. I am confused !

Comment: The first example doesn't contain an adjective phrase. The part in bold is the noun phrase built around *man*. The words *the* and *who I saw yesterday* modify *man*. Perhaps it is the latter part that confuses you, because it is a relative clause within the noun phrase.

Comment: And yes, that last phrase is the same as what you understood from your sentence. It is also a better than your version with a gerund which is why I recommend you use it ;)

Comment: Got it , Thanks. Sorry for my terrible English. And the final question, in the second highlighted noun phrase, I think "that" is the conjunction and we have M.Clause and Sb.Clause. am I right ?

Comment: No need to apologise for your English, it's fine! This site is for learning ;) And to answer your question: No, *that* is not a coordinator. It is a *subordinating conjunction*. It links the *subordinate clause* to the main clause. A *coordinator* or *coordinating conjunction* links two main clauses.

Comment: I noticed that and then immediately corrected it. I was not talking about the nature of the "that". I said it is strange to me to consider "that i saw.." as a noun clause. It sounds to me as M.C and Sb.C with the conjunction "that"

Comment: Well, that is the thing about *noun clauses*. As opposed to a noun phrase, they are not built around a noun. They merely act like a noun within the main clause. Have a look at this, it might help: http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/noun_clauses.htm

Answer (score 0):

You parsed the sentence correctly.  "Having" is a gerund, "having mentor ..." is a noun phrase (or is it a clause?  I confuse the two, sorry).

Comment: Did you mean *incorrectly*?

Comment: Why, no.  "83 ... businesses" is the subject, "report" is the predicate, "having blahblah" is the object.

Comment: But if *having mentor* is a noun phrase, isn't it missing an article (or another determiner)?

Comment: That is, if each of them only had one mentor to report...

Comment: Oh sorry, it was typo

Comment: So, It is certainly a noun clause. isn't it ? The additional question is there any concerns on longevity of a noun clause ?

Comment: Yes, it is a noun clause. A noun clause is an entire clause that functions as a noun within the main clause.

Comment: Longevity?  You mean "length"?  I wouldn't worry about it.  And, it's "of the noun clause" since you mean that particular one, I believe.

Comment: nope, i was talking generally. and in case of length, i admit :D

Comment: @Cardinal "longevity" means an amount of time, not length. If you say the "longevity" of this phrase it makes it sound as if you think it will become obsolete in the future.

Comment: @Cardinal, To answer your question, I'd recommend keeping noun clause lengths under control since it's possible to get the reader lost.  In this case it's fine.  Longer?  Only if you have to.

Comment: @VictorBazarov I agree with you. In fact, I hadn't seen such a long noun clause before.

Comment: @Cardinal Thanks to the magic of prepositions, English sentences and clauses can be made arbitrarily longer. In this case, "when they were younger" can be removed from the sentence and it will still make sense.

Comment: @CrazyEyes thus, we can use when where whose  ...  in the chain ? is it correct, regardless of sounding uncanny, in terms of grammar ? or that that that that ... ? :)

Comment: @Cardinal Not in a chain necessarily, but prepositional phrases in English are just "fluff" grammatically; they may add very important information to a sentence, but in the grammatical structure they're optional. Prepositional phrases can be chained if you're discussing different attributes of something. For instance, "Let's meet (by the coffee shop) (at 2 PM)." Parenthesis show the phrases. This sentence can be reduced to "Let's meet" and still be valid. Generally, prepositions answer the question of "when," "where" and possibly "how," and you should use one phrase to answer each "question."

Comment: @CrazyEyes Not always. In "The cat is on the sofa" the PP is a subject complement; in "I put the cat on the sofa" the PP is an object complement; in "On the sofa is where the cat  is" the PP is the subject; these cannot be omitted.